# Making Dataset for 4 Motors Inverse kinematics using ANFIS in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, robotics, inverse, kinematics

This is the link that explain to solve inverse kinematics using ANFIS
http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/examples/modeling-inverse-kinematics-in-a-robotic-arm.html

But the example is only for 2 DOFs Robot. How to make the data set if the robot using 4 motors? 
Because there is always an error that says :"Error using meshgrid. Too many input arguments." when running the code:

```
a= 0:(1*pi/180):(180*pi/180);
b= 0:(1*pi/180):(180*pi/180);
c= 0:(1*pi/180):(180*pi/180);
d= (25*180/pi):(1*pi/180):(180*pi/180);

[THETA1, THETA2, THETA3, THETA4] = meshgrid(a, b, c, d);
```

Any Suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meshgrid` is specifically for 2D or 3D data. For arbitrary n-dimensional data, the appropriately-named [`ndgrid`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) is the guy you want.

Note that `meshgrid` is intended for working intuitively with Cartesian *X,Y{,Z}* data, so swaps the first two dimensions in the shape of its output to reflect *X,Y* order rather than *row,column*. `ndgrid`, being more general, just gives you standard multidimensional matrix order.